# Get annotated instance variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

[PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations) introduced syntax for variable annotations, that can be added on an instance variable even when the value is  not defined.

```
class BasicStarship:
    captain: str = 'Picard'               # instance variable with default
    damage: int                           # instance variable without default
```

But when I list the instance variables, the one without value is not listed:

```
starship = BasicStarship()
dir(starship) #doesn't return 'damage' field
```

How can I get all instance variable, including the ones without value?

Comment: Did you set `damage` in the `BasicStarship.__init__()`? If not, then the attribute was never added to the instance.

Comment: You can use e.g. `starship.__annotations__`, but `starship` *doesn't* have a `damage` attribute, nor does `BasicStarship`, so `dir` certainly won't show it.

Comment: Did you intend to make this a DataClass?

Answer (score 1):

[`__annotations__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) shows it:

```
>>> starship.__annotations__
{'captain': <class 'str'>, 'damage': <class 'int'>}
```

> A dict containing annotations of parameters. The keys of the dict are the parameter names, and 'return' for the return annotation, if provided.

Although, note, from your link:

> [T]he value-less notation `a: int` allows one to annotate instance variables **that should be initialized in `__init__` or `__new__`**.

So, you should be setting it anyway if you're going to do that, in which case it will show up in `dir`.